# How can I type a password when fprint is enabled?

Tags: fedora, password, authentication, input, fingerprint

I use Fedora 34. I love what `fprint` is doing when it allows me to authenticate using my fingerprints on my ThinkPad's built-in fingerprint reader, but when I'm in my office, I like to dock my laptop and close the lid. I will use my external monitor, keyboard, and mouse during that time.

However, there are times that I need to authenticate, and it asks for my fingerprint. Since the fingerprint reader isn't easily accessible, I'd rather simply switch to typing my password.

Do I have to actually disable `fprint` in order to make authentication functional when I don't have access to the fingerprint reader, or is there a way to get it to fallback to password typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you but, paraphrasing `/usr/share/doc/fprintd-pam/README`:

```
Known issues:
* pam_fprintd doesn't support entering either the password or a fingerprint
```

Comment: So basically, I'm out of luck as of right now. Thanks for the info. I'll mark your answer as the solution.